# Delete a calendar from Evolution

Tags: evolution

I imported my Google calendar into Evolution and now I can't find a way to delete the calendar. How can I delete it?

Comment: I have a simmilar problem but this answers here doesnt help me
http://askubuntu.com/questions/206219/how-to-delete-a-google-calendar-from-evolution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have imported it the right way (New Calendar => Type Google), you can remove it right-clicking on the calendar name and then deleting it.
If you have imported a CVS/ICS calendar file (Google calendar => Export),  this approach doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Some calendars can't be just be removed using the UI (as added by online accounts), the only way I've found is to manually remove the matching sources from `~/.config/evolution/sources/`. You can easily grep the ones you want remove by checking the `DisplayName` on them (they're in plain text).

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the calendars were shown because I added my Google accounts from the GNOME settings.

> [image: screenshot]

When I added the accounts, I choose to use also their calendars, thinking I could later delete the ones I didn't need. I then discovered Evolution doesn't allow me to delete calendars.

What I did was opening the GNOME settings again, click on the accounts listed there, and deselect *Calendar* from them.

> [image: screenshot]

I didn't need to remove the accounts and re-add them. Once I deselected *Calendar* from my Google accounts, I just closed Evolution and re-opened it. The Google calendars stopped to appear on Evolution.

Comment: I'm on LinuxMint 19.1 Cinnamon and this was my problem. This applies to Cinnamon as well as GNOME.

Comment: so what am I supposed to do if I want to keep one calendar from that account and remove others? God this is annoying...

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue, and found that I could delete calendars if I shut down the clock applet first.

- Go to System → *Administration* → *System Monitor*
- Click on *clock-applet* and then on *End process*

Don't restart when prompted to do so. You should now be able to delete your calendars.

To get the clock applet back, you may have to add it back to your panel by <kbd>right-clicking</kbd> on it, selecting *Add to panel*, then *Clock*, and placing it where you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: I could not remove the Google calendar, nor the contacts.

My solution was to:

1. Remove the Gmail account (so calendar and contacts were also removed)
2. Add the Gmail account again, choosing not to add calendar and contacts