# Remove online account from evolution

Tags: gnome, evolution

I am using Evolution for my company mail account and I have a GMail account. I am using GMail Notify Gnome extension, which notifies me if I have unread messages in my GMail account. GMail Notify requires online account to be setup in GNome in order to be able to check GMail for e-mails. I read my GMail in browser and I don't want it to be in Evolution. However, I cannot delete GMail account from Evolution because it is added to Evolution as soon as I create an online account in GNome.

Is there a way not to show GMail account in Evolution and have it configured in GNome online accounts?

The closest I got was when local evolution database for GMail was corrupted and the mail account did't work in Evolution. Now I disabled e-mail checking for GMail account within Evolution. It is there and doing nothing, but it would be better if I could remove it from Evolution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found a solution to this problem myself.

In Gnome online accounts I have added my GMail account, but I switched everything in that account to off. So there is a GMail account but where is says "Use for": mail, calendar, contacts, chat, documents, photos, printers, I have switched the all off. Now the GMail Notifier extension for Gnome works but GMail is no longer present in Evolution. That is what I wanted.